# event on more than one button group in java

Tags: java

in my java application there is 60 button groups and each group has two radio buttons yes or no buttons.how to know that which group ,button is selected

```
   import javax.swing.*;
        class buttonGroup{
         JToggleButton yes[],no[];
           JPanel yesNo[];
           ButtonGroup group[];
        public void init()
        {
 yesNo=new JPanel[60];
            yes=new JToggleButton[60];
            no=new JToggleButton[60];
            group=new ButtonGroup[60];
        for(int i=0;i<60;i++)
{
 yesNo[i]=new JPanel();
                   yes[i]=new JToggleButton("yes");
                   no[i]=new JToggleButton("no");
                   group[i]=new ButtonGroup();
yesNo[i].add(yes[i]);
                   yesNo[i].add(no[i]);
                   group[i].add(yes[i]);
                   group[i].add(no[i]);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method **actionPerformed** use **getSource()** to know from where the action is fired

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource.equals(//put the object here ){
       // implementation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

class buttonGroup implements ActionListener
{
    JToggleButton yes[], no[];
    JPanel yesNo[];
    ButtonGroup group[];

    public void init()
    {
        yesNo = new JPanel[60];
        yes = new JToggleButton[60];
        no = new JToggleButton[60];
        group = new ButtonGroup[60];
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            yesNo[i] = new JPanel();
            yes[i] = new JToggleButton("yes");
            yes[i].setName("yes" + " " + i);
            yes[i].addActionListener(this);
            no[i] = new JToggleButton("no");
            no[i].setName("no" + " " + i);
            no[i].addActionListener(this);
            group[i] = new ButtonGroup();
            yesNo[i].add(yes[i]);
            yesNo[i].add(no[i]);
            group[i].add(yes[i]);
            group[i].add(no[i]);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent sE)
    {
        if(sE.getSource() instanceof JToggleButton)
        {
            JToggleButton oSourceButton = (JToggleButton) sE.getSource();
            System.out.println("Button " + oSourceButton.getName() + " was pressed...");
            // do whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is need to set name for each button can you please explain

Comment: if you follow my code, you'll see also the name is set for each button like: yes[i].setName("yes" + " " + i);